# find_or_create_by - not updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'd like to submit a product ID and a retailer ID to my controller, if that combo exisiting in the DB I want to update that record with the submitted params, if not, create a new record.

My controller is below and currently I can see that if the the combo does not exist the record is created but when the combo is found it does a select query and the record is not updated.

How can I get it to update and not just select?

Thanks

Controller:

```
      def AddNewPrice
            @newPrice = ProductPrice.find_or_create_by(product_id: params[:product_id], retailer_id: params[:retailer_id])                  
      end
```

**Update**

Sorry..Just to mentioned, when I update I want to update the price attribute that comes in as a param

Comment: WHAT are you trying to update in case the record is found? Because I don't see any extra update commands. The found-row would already have the values that you're querying for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As, its clear from method name that it finds record matching given conditions, or create a new record with product_id, and retailer_id given, if record does't exists.
You need to do some thing like this to update records

```
def add_new_price
  new_price = ProductPrice.find_or_create_by(product_id: params[:product_id], retailer_id: params[:retailer_id])
  new_price.update_attributes({attr: params[:attr]})
end
```

Comment: This way the product price will be created then updated which will run two queries to update and three queries to create.

Answer (score 8):

What you're trying to do is actually create a record if the combination of `product_id` and `retailer_id` does not exist. If it does exist then there's nothing to do..

If you want to update attributes if it exists or create it if it doesn't you can use `find_or_initialize_by` along with `update_attributes`

```
def AddNewPrice
  @newPrice = ProductPrice.find_or_initialize_by(product_id: params[:product_id], retailer_id: params[:retailer_id])
  @newPrice.update_attributes(price: "updated value")                  
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Like the method name suggests it *finds* the object if it exists and *creates* it if not.

If you want to update something you can do something like this:

```
def AddNewPrice
  @newPrice = ProductPrice.find_or_create_by(product_id: params[:product_id], retailer_id: params[:retailer_id])
  @newPrice.my_attribute = 'updated value'
  @newPrice.save
end
```