# Use the edit form to create a new object if a certain attribute has changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a User model, and attached to it is a Contact model that takes various attributes like address, city, state, email, etc.

The problem I have is that I need to create a new contact record anytime someone updates their email address using the contact edit form (so we keep track of all of the email addresses that have been associated with that user account), but that is the ONLY time I want people to create a new contact record. Otherwise, we can just update the old one. I know I can do this by creating a separate form for updating an email address but this is not the route that we want to go.

I have tried to do this using active record callbacks and the dirty module, but then the `before_save` callback seems to also get called when saving the newly created record and I wind up in a stack level too deep situation.

I'm not sure what the best way to do this in rails is.. it seems more logical to me to put something like that in the controller, but I haven't been able to figure out a way to do this. I have searched around for a similar issue but all I could find were people accidentally creating new records on submitting the edit form

I tried using an active record callback:

```rb
before_save :create_new_contact, if: :email_changed?
```

```rb
def create_new_contact
    new_attributes = self.attributes.except('id', 'verified', 'start_date', 'end_date', 'created_at', 'updated_at')
    new_attributes.merge!('verified' => false, 'start_date' => Date.today, 'end_date' => Date.today + 10.years)
    new_contact = Contact.new(new_attributes)
    new_contact.save
    self.restore_attributes
    self.end_date = Date.today
    self.save
  end
```

I expected this to revert the changes to the old record and create a new record, but I got a stack level too deep error. If I remove the `new_contact.save` it gets rid of the stack level too deep error, but obviously does not save the new contact information.

Comment: When you call new_contact.save rails is calling before_save again, and then again, and...  You can do this in a controller instead of the model I would think.

Comment: @BenTrewern that was my thought as well but I don't think I have access to ActiveModel::Dirty from the controller?

Comment: You should be able to check whether a field has changed in your controller but I'm not sure you need to though.  Just find the contact `@contact = Contact.find(params[:id])` then check to see if the email has been changed `if @contact.email != params[:contact][:email]` or similar.

Comment: have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30107788/9446028 ? you can do `Contact.find_or_create_by(email: email)`